# Relational algebra with aggregates

Tags: mysql, sql

For each ward that admitted more than 10 patients today, list the ward name, ward type and number of beds in each ward

Give the following schema:

```
Patient(PatNo, patName, patAddress, DOB)
Ward (wardNo, wardName, wardType, noOfBeds)
Contains (PatNo, WardNo, admissionDate)
```

Here is my SQL:

```
select PatNo, wardNo, wardName, wardType, noOfBeds
  from Ward w , Contains c
 where w.wardNo = c.WardNo 
   and count(c.patNo) > 10 
   and c.admissionDate = getDate();
```

I don't understand how to use aggregates with relational algebra.

Comment: Iswanto San thanks for editing my question, I'm very new on the site. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Two things.  First,

```
and c.admissionDate = getDate();
```

getDate() returns a datetime so this will almost never return anything.  You probably want

```
and c.admissionDate = cast(getDate() as date);
```

Next, you don't want your aggregate in the where clause.  You want either:

```
having count(c.PatNo) > 10
```

or

```
and (subquery to get admitted patient count) > 10
```

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL function for the current date is `now()` rather than `getdate()`.  Try this:

```
select PatNo, wardNo, wardName, wardType, noOfBeds
  from Ward w join
       Contains c
       on w.wardNo = c.WardNo 
 where c.admissionDate = date(now())
 group by c.patno
 having count(c.patNo) > 10
```

Your query needs a `group by` clause for the aggregation.  The condition on `count` needs to be in a `having` clause rather than in a `where` clause (which is used before aggregation rather than after).

I changed the query to use standard joins.